# Return value based on row number in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

In a google sheet with values in 2 sheets columns A1:A how can I return the corresponding nonblank value in sheet #2 whose non-blank row number is the same as the non-blank row number in sheet #1.

I have tried using the following in Sheet1

```
arrayformula(IFERROR(IF(A2:A<>"",vlookup(IF(A2:A<>"",ROW(A2:A)-ROW(A2)+1,""), Sheet2!A2:B,2,FALSE),"")))
```

and then in Sheet2 used `ArrayFormula(IF(B2:B<>"",ROW(B2:B)-ROW(B2)+1,""))` as a helper column to create corresponding row number that can be used as a vlookup but I feel there should be a better way to do this, that is much easier.

Perhaps there is a way to use an arrayformula() that will count the number within a list of a particular nonblank value in sheet 1 and then set that as a row number parameter to look up a value in Sheet 2  `=index(Sheet2!A2:A,parameter)`

**Sheet 1**

| Name |
| --- |
| john |
| mary |

**Sheet 2**

| values |
| --- |
| blue |
| green |
| red |

**Desired output with formula in Sheet2!B2**

| Name |  |
| --- | --- |
| john | blue [formula in this cell] |
| mary | green |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By creating a range with curly brackets, you could try with QUERY for example with same amount of rows:

```
=QUERY({Sheet1!A2:A1000,Sheet2!A2:A1000},"Where Col1 is not null AND Col2 is not null",)
```

Or FILTER:

```
=FILTER({Sheet1!A2:A1000,Sheet2!A2:A1000},Sheet1!A2:A1000<>"",Sheet2!A2:A1000<>"")
```

Comment: how can these both be modified so that the output appears when formula is placed in Sheet1!b2 (modified question to reflect location)

Comment: Isn't it Sheet1!B2?

Comment: IF it's so, you can place: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A<>"",Sheet2!A2:A,""))`